Saw tooth orange sign appears when connecting wire to a component pin
I see in my schematic that when I connect a wire to a component pin a saw tooth orange sign appears on the pin:

Does this representing an error? and how can remove it?(Nets containing floating input pins)


Software specific questions should be asked in the Altium forums. Yes, this is an error marker. What is the error message?

This link will take you, even without a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: https://forum.live.altium.com (where all you need to do is register for an account).

@ Chris Knudsen thanks, I checked and it mentioned "Sorry the Forum is not available", I remember i tried it also 3 weeks ago and I got the same result. Would you please let me know if you have access now?

@Andromeda I logged in to the forum using Chris Knudsens link just now, 7 minutes after your comment, and it works fine here. Navigating subforums and threads and everything.

@MrGerber I even made an new account with a new email, but still it is not working

Identifying the issue
There are (at least) two ways to find out how to remove that squiggly line.

If you hover your mouse over it, a box will pop up and tell you what the error message is.
Validating the design through the project panel or "Project" on the menu bar, will put all your design errors and warnings in the messages panel.



That will tell you how to fix the issue it's reporting.
Mitigating the issue(s)
Following the rules
The best approach (at least for a beginner) is typically to try to design in such a way as to comply with the verification checks that Altium does, until you get a feeling for which ones apply for any given time for any given project.
Changing the rules
The other way to get the messages away is to either change the rules, which you can do from the project options, on the "Error Reporting" and "Connection Matrix" tabs.


Supressing the rules
The other way is to suppress the individual violations by placing "NO ERC"-markers. You might have seen them as one of the following markers on a schematic:

They can be configured to either suppress all violations, or specific violations, through the properties panel (by selecting them and choosing the appropriate settings)
Read more about design validation on The Altium help article (archive.org link)
Which is also the source of all the images in this answer
Disclaimer: As always with software, it changes over time, and this might not be the correct method for Altium in the future, but this method has been the way at least from AD17 until AD24 (the version as per writing)

@ MrGerber thank you for your comprehensive answer.  I edited the post and added the error in, would you please let me know how to fix it? the error is Nets containing floating input pins.
